# Current page hightlight button

Tags: php, html, css

I have 3 buttons that are in a header PHP file of my site. I want to change the color of the button when you are on a that page but I cannot get it working correctly so I am trying to use $thispage statement to call it so if it is on one of the pages it adds the id="currentpage." Here is the code I am using

```
<input type='button' value='AVAILABLE NOW' onClick='location="/category/upcoming/"' <?php if ($thisPage) echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?> class="header-image" />
<input type='button' value='COMING SOON' onClick='location="/category/soon/"' <?php if ($thisPage) echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>class="header-image" />
<input type='button' value='VAULT ARCHIVE' onClick='location="/category/previous/"' <?php if ($thisPage) echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>class="header-image" />
```

Comment: `if ($thisPage)` those should read something like `if ($thisPage=="page_x.php")` and we don't know where you're assigning that variable as.

Comment: Add `currentpage` as a class instead of an `id` as id are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP

```
<?php
$page_name = basename(__FILE__);
?>
```

HTML

```
 <li <?php echo ($page_name == 'page1.php' ? 'class="currentpage"' : 'class="h"'); ?>><a href="whatever.php"> Link1</a></li>
 <li <?php echo ($page_name == 'page2.php' ? 'class="currentpage"' : 'class="h"'); ?>><a href="whatever.php"> Page 2</a></li>
```

CSS

```
.currentpage{
/*Format it how you want it */
}
```